# How to read PDF files from multilist using glass mapper?

Tags: glass-mapper, pdf

I have uploaded all PDF files under media library. In one of my template, I added multilist with datasource to the pdf files which are created under media Library.
Now in my code,I have to read the PDF files selected in the multilist from Sitecore.

I have added like below for the field in my Model.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<File> Documents { get; set; }
```

While reading  the data from the GlassMapper it is throwing an exception as below.

> Message = "Failed to map properties on to the Item"

Please suggest a way to read the PDF files from Sitecore using GlassMapper

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a model first for your media items, e.g.:

```
[SitecoreClass]
public class MediaFile
{
    [SitecoreField("Attachment")]
    public virtual Stream File {get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("MimeType")]
    public virtual string MimeType { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("Title")]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("Size")]
    public virtual string Size { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField("Extension")]
    public virtual string Extension { get; set; }  
}
```

and then use it in your model:

```
[SitecoreField]
public virtual IEnumerable<MediaFile> Documents {get;set;}
```

Comment: What using statement is needed here for `SitecoreClass`?

Comment: `using Glass.Sitecore.Mapper.Configuration.Attributes;`

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you need to do with those pdfs I would keep it as Item and used MediaManager to work with it

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Item> Documents { get; set; }
```

You can then use it like

```
foreach(var document in Model.Documents){
    MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(document);
}
```